# How to pass parameters to facebook Graph Search Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

i want to pass my parameters to this url .

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=music.fields(videos)

it is easy to pass a parameters to `https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=music` , for this i am using , Bundle parameters like

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();<br>
bun.putString("fields", "music");
```

but i stuck at `music.fields(videos)` Section unable to find a proper way to send parameters to url , for this i have tried

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("fields", "music");
bun.putString("music", "name");
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing this , i got what i want ,

```
Bundle bun = new Bundle();
bun.putString("fields", "music.fields(videos)");
```